# Shared memory file in PHP

Tags: php, windows, file, shared-memory

I use `openssl_pkcs7_sign` and `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt` to create encrypted data. The functions only accept file names. I would like to store the temporary files in shared memory to improve performance. I understand in Linux I can `file_put_contents('/dev/shm/xxx', data)`, but it is not possible for Windows. Is there portable way in PHP to do this? Would `shmop_` function help here? Thanks.

PS: Or is there way to make these functions accept data strings?

PS2: Please do not suggest invoking `/usr/bin/openssl` from PHP. It is not portable.

Comment: what do you want to do with it once you save it?  Have you thought about using a file stream instead of shared memory?  see [StreamWrapper](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php)

Comment: I just save data to the file (using `file_put_contents`) and feed the file name to the OpenSSL functions. Most of the overhead is from the OpenSSL functions and VFS operations (read, write, unlink). How does streaming make difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Windows 2000, the `shmop` (previously `shm_`) methods are available.

`shmop_open` uses a unique integer key to share the memory area.  `ftok` can be used to produce a unique index based on a file path (typically your script file's full path).  Any instance that shares the same key can share the same memory.

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php

Tested on PHP Version 5.3.3 from Zend Server CE
System  Windows NT CRYPE 6.1 build 7601 (Unknow Windows version Business Edition Service Pack 1) i586

```
<?php
$key = ftok(__FILE__, 't');
$memory = shmop_open($key, "c", 0600, 16 * 1024);
$data = array('data' => 'value');
$bytes = shmop_write($memory, serialize($data), 0);
$return = shmop_read($memory, 0, $bytes);
print_r(unserialize($return));
?>
```

`shmop_read`/`shmop_write` stores raw bytes from a string, so you don't need to serialize it, but you will need to write the length of the string somewhere.  My example creates a 16KB shared memory area, you can of course size it to fit the openssl file plus the space you need to store the file size.

Comment: I understand the `shmop_` functions. My question is how do you feed the file name to OpenSSL? Memory blocks do not have file names.

Comment: It doesn't look like most of the OpenSSL functions accept file pointers, which would have let you use the ``php://memory`` memory files. You'll have to use temporary files to read the data in and out, which would negate any benefits of shared memory in my opinion.  However, some functions like openssl_private_decrypt allow you to work with strings instead of files, which you could load and unload directly from shared memory. There are other MIME functions which may work instead of pkcs7 but I'm not that familiar.  I'd recommend looking to see if any of those functions will work for your needs.

Comment: In addition you can use shmop_size to recover the block size.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, so the way I would suggest doing this is with a file [stream wrapper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.streamwrapper.php).  Let me whip up a quick example:

```
class staticStreamWrapper {
    public $context;
    protected static $data = array();

    protected $path    = '';
    protected $pointer = 0;
    protected $writable = false;

    public function stream_close() {}

    public function stream_eof() {
        return $this->pointer >= strlen(static::$data[$this->path]);
    }

    public function stream_flush() {}

    public function stream_open($path, $mode, $options, &$opened_path) {
        switch ($mode[0]) {
            case 'r':
                if (!isset(static::$data[$path])) return false;
                $this->path = $path;
                $this->writable = isset($mode[1]) && $mode[1] == '+';
                break;
            case 'w':
                static::$data[$path] = '';
                $this->path = $path;
                $this->writable = true;
                break;
            case 'a':
                if (!isset(static::$data[$path])) static::$data[$path] = '';
                $this->path = $path;
                $this->writable = true;
                $this->pointer = strlen(static::$data[$path]);
                break;
            case 'x':
                if (isset(static::$data[$path])) return false;
                $this->path = $path;
                $this->writable = true;
                break;
            case 'c':
                if (!isset(static::$data[$path])) static::$data[$path] = '';
                $this->path = $path;
                $this->writable = true;
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        $opened_path = $this->path;
        return true;
    }
   
    public function stream_read($count) {
        $bytes = min(strlen(static::$data[$this->path]) - $this->pointer, $count);
        $data = substr(static::$data[$this->path], $this->pointer, $bytes);
        $this->pointer += $bytes;
        return $data;
    }

    public function stream_seek($offset, $whence = SEEK_SET) {
        $len = strlen(static::$data[$this->path]);
        switch ($whence) {
            case SEEK_SET:
                if ($offset <= $len) {
                    $this->pointer = $offset;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case SEEK_CUR:
                if ($this->pointer + $offset <= $len) {
                    $this->pointer += $offset;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
            case SEEK_END:
                if ($len + $offset <= $len) {
                    $this->pointer = $len + $offset;
                    return true;
                }
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function stream_stat() {
        $size = strlen(static::$data[$this->path]);
        $time = time();
        return array(
            0 => 0,
            'dev' => 0,
            1 => 0,
            'ino' => 0,
            2 => 0777,
            'mode' => 0777,
            3 => 1,
            'nlink' => 1,
            4 => 0,
            'uid' => 0,
            5 => 0,
            'gid' => 0,
            6 => '',
            'rdev' => '',
            7 => $size,
            'size' => $size,
            8 => $time,
            'atime' => $time,
            9 => $time,
            'mtime' => $time,
            10 => $time,
            'ctime' => $time,
            11 => -1,
            'blksize' => -1,
            12 => -1,
            'blocks' => -1,
        );
    }

    public function stream_tell() {
        return $this->pointer;
    }

    public function stream_write($data) {
        if (!$this->writable) return 0;
        $size = strlen($data);
        $len = strlen(static::$data[$this->path]);
        if ($this->stream_eof()) {
            static::$data[$this->path] .= $data;
        } else {
            static::$data[$this->path] = substr_replace(
                static::$data[$this->path],
                $data,
                $this->pointer
            );
        }
        $this->pointer += $size;
        return $size;
    }

    public function unlink($path) {
        if (isset(static::$data[$path])) {
            unset(static::$data[$path]);
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Now, you would then need to register the wrapper:

```
stream_wrapper_register('static', 'staticStreamWrapper');
```

So you now can treat it like a file even though it never actually leaves PHP (it's stored as a static variable)!

```
file_put_contents('static://foo.txt', 'this is my data');
file_get_contents('static://foo.txt'); // "this is my data"
$f = fopen('static://foo.txt', 'r'); // should return a resource
// etc...
```

Comment: Thanks for the stream info. I understand that PHP supports custom stream wrapper implementation. However, the OpenSSL extension is most likely be written with OS APIs, and the functions do not utilize the PHP streams. Calling `openssl_pkcs7_encrypt` with `static` stream results in the following error message: `error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory`.