# Shared Memory between PHP an QT

Tags: php, c++, qt

i would like to ask if it is possible to create a shared memory between a qt-application and a php-script.

I looked around and came out with the following (quite simple) idea :

qt - side

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    unsigned char data[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    QSharedMemory smem;
    smem.setNativeKey("12345");
    qDebug() << smem.nativeKey();

    if(smem.create(4096)){
        qDebug() << "SharedMemory created.";
        char *to = (char*)smem.data();
        memcpy(to,data,5);
    }
    return a.exec();
 }
```

php - side

```
<?php
        $shm_ = shmop_open("12345", "w", 0,0);

        if($shm_==FALSE){
            echo "SHM Open Failed!";
        }else{
            $shm_s = shmop_size($shm_);
            echo "SHM Open Succ! [Size : ".$shm_s."]<br>";
            $data_read = shmop_read($shm_,0,5);
            shmop_close($shm_);
        }

?>
```

But this approach fails. shmop_open() says : unable to attach or create shared memory. (running xampp on windows / qt ver.5.5)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically this seems to be possible. However practically this usually falls short because of the different shared-memory implementations of the different platforms. Qt implements its own `QSharedMemory` class on top of other system specific API's (which are different on different platforms). PHP may do the same.

You need to find the technique that is compatible on both ends. Look out for the most os-specific approach, as there might be the common denominator. I'm not that experienced on the Linux platform but:

For the Windows platform I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669631/shared-memory-file-in-php) that describes file-based shared memory from within PHP. On the Qt side you could use the [normal Windows API](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjzmrmZkrTKAhUH2SwKHXFqArsQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fwindows%2Fdesktop%2Faa366551(v%3Dvs.85).aspx&usg=AFQjCNFHIXt4AlQoQrdwuU34TpKJeMYeLw&sig2=GmxOCE9QJADeRWFr4c_TUA&bvm=bv.112064104,d.bGg&cad=rja) functions. There's a high chance that the two match.

## Alternative

Another approach would be to use sockets. At first it might look like an overkill to use the network stack for interprocess communication, but this has two clear advantages:

1. Communication over localhost are fast. I've personally made tests on a Windows machine, comparing it to real shared memory. The network solution overhead was comparable to that of a single `memcpy()` call.
2. Network code is inherently compatible, and both, Qt and PHP are well suited for that type of communication.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Thought QSharedMem is build on top of Windows API. I tried a websocket comm already but wanted to speed up my task by using shared memory. But your post helped me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I am pretty sure that QSharedMem is "somehow" built on top of Windows API. It's the details that matter here. If you study the Windows API you see that there are several ways to create shared memory regions. All of them are somehow related but not necessarily compatible.